# Nginx rewrite rule for specific request

Tags: nginx, url, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite a specific request url using nginx, but I've only gotten so far as either a permanent redirect loop or no rewrite at all.

The rewrite rule I'm trying to achieve is the following:

FROM `https://localhost/api/economic/grantaccess?id=123&token=foobar`

TO `https://localhost/customer-api/api/economic/grantaccess?id=123&token=foobar`

I'm just looking to add `/customer-api/` to this specific request, any other requests should be picked up by the `/customer-api/` location. Meaning that after the redirect is made to `https://localhost/customer-api/api/economic/grantaccess?id=123&token=foobar` the location that should be used to serve that request should be `/customer-api/` so that the proxy_pass kicks in and connects to the backend.

Here is my simplified nginx config:

```
http {

  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  server_tokens off;

  upstream customerapi {
      zone customerapi 64k;
      server 127.0.0.1:6564;
  }

  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name localhost;
      root /apps;
      index index.html;
    
      location ~ /api/economic/grantaccess(.*)$ {´
         rewrite ^ /customer-api/api/economic/grantaccess$1$is_args$args break;
      }
    
      location /customer-api/ {
         rewrite ^ $request_uri;
         rewrite ^/customer-api/(.*) $1 break;
         return 400;
         proxy_pass http://customerapi/$uri;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
      }
 
    }
 }
```

When using `break` flag the rewrite does not work at all because nginx tries to open the new path as a file in the filesystem instead of picking up the request via the /customer-api/ location, and if I use `permanent` flag I get stuck in a permanent redirect loop.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Use `last` if you want `rewrite` to search for a new `location` to process the rewritten request. See [the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite). Also, your `$1` is empty as `^` contains no captures and numeric captures cannot pass from a previous regular expression. Also, `$is_args$args` will duplicate the arguments as `rewrite` appends arguments automatically.